# Jasmine - how to write custom matcher to sum two numbers?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine 2.1.3 and trying to create a custom matcher to sum two numbers.

However I am getting:

```
Expected 24 not to equal 12
```

So far I have

```
it("is 24 for 24", function() {
  result = simpleMath.sum_of(12,12); // gets 24
  expect(result).toBeSumOf([12,12]);
});
```

and

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    simpleMath = new SimpleMath();
    jasmine.addMatchers({
      toBeSumOf: function (util, customEqualityTesters) {
        return {
          compare: function(actual, expected) {
            // var passed = actual == expected  // comparison example that worked
            var passed = (actual[0]+actual[1]) == expected;
            return {
              pass: passed,
              message: 'Expected ' + actual + (passed ? '' : ' not') + ' to equal ' + expected
            };
          }
        };
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: updated to use `toBeSumOf([12,12])` as that was not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual and expected are the wrong way around, just add:

```
console.log(actual);
console.log(expected);
```

To your matcher and you'll see, you can use either format for the parameters 12, 12 or [12, 12] but for the former you'll need to add another parameter so the array format is probably preferable. You could of course use an object if that helps for more complex comparisons/matchers.

Working (array based) example:

```
describe("My custom test", function() {
  it("should work", function() {
      var result = 12 + 12;
      expect(result).toBeSumOf([12, 12]);
  });
});
```

and:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  jasmine.addMatchers({
    toBeSumOf: function () {
      return {
        compare: function (actual, expected) {

            var passed = (actual == expected[0] + expected[1]);
            return {
              pass: passed,
              message: 'Expected value ' + (expected[0] + expected[1]) + (passed ? '' : ' not') + ' equal to ' + actual
            };
        }
      };
    }
  });
});
```

Gives:

[image: Pass!]

Changing one of the values gives:

[image: Fail!]

Comment: I ended up going with `[12,12]`